# How to Do a Simple CLI Query for a Saved Estimator Model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, command-line

I have successfully trained a DNNClassifier to classify texts (posts from an online discussion board). I've saved the model and I now want to classify texts using the TensorFlow CLI.

When I run `saved_model_cli show` for my saved model, I get this output:

```
saved_model_cli show --dir /my/model --tag_set serve --signature_def predict
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['examples'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_STRING
      shape: (-1)
      name: input_example_tensor:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
  outputs['class_ids'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_INT64
      shape: (-1, 1)
      name: dnn/head/predictions/ExpandDims:0
  outputs['classes'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_STRING
      shape: (-1, 1)
      name: dnn/head/predictions/str_classes:0
  outputs['logistic'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 1)
      name: dnn/head/predictions/logistic:0
  outputs['logits'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 1)
      name: dnn/logits/BiasAdd:0
  outputs['probabilities'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 2)
      name: dnn/head/predictions/probabilities:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

I cannot figure out the correct parameters for `saved_model_cli run` to get a prediction.

I have tried several approaches, for example:

```
saved_model_cli run --dir /my/model --tag_set serve --signature_def predict --input_exprs='examples=["klassifiziere mich bitte"]'
```

Which gives me this error message:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Could not parse example input, value: 'klassifiziere mich bitte'
 [[Node: ParseExample/ParseExample = ParseExample[Ndense=1, Nsparse=0, Tdense=[DT_STRING], dense_shapes=[[1]], sparse_types=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_input_example_tensor_0_0, ParseExample/ParseExample/names, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_0, ParseExample/ParseExample/names)]]
```

**What is the correct way to pass my input string to the CLI to get a classification?**

You can find the code of my project, including the training data, on GitHub: https://github.com/pahund/beitragstuev

I'm building and saving my model like this (simplified, [see GitHub for original code](https://github.com/pahund/beitragstuev/blob/master/utils/estimator.py)):

```
embedded_text_feature_column = hub.text_embedding_column(
    key="sentence",
    module_spec="https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-de-dim128/1")
feature_columns = [embedded_text_feature_column]
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    hidden_units=[500, 100],
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    n_classes=2,
    optimizer=tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.003))
feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns)
serving_input_receiver_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)
estimator.export_savedmodel(export_dir_base="/my/dir/base", serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

Comment: can you provide a minimal example of code used to create/save your model?

Comment: I've added a link to my GitHub repo. Pls let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ServingInputReceiver` you're creating for the model export is is telling the saved model to expect serialized `tf.Example` protos instead of the raw strings you wish to classify.

From [the Save and Restore documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#using_savedmodel_with_estimators):

> A typical pattern is that inference requests arrive in the form of serialized tf.Examples, so the serving_input_receiver_fn() creates a single string placeholder to receive them. The serving_input_receiver_fn() is then also responsible for parsing the tf.Examples by adding a tf.parse_example op to the graph.
>
> ....
>
> **The tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn utility function provides that input receiver for the common case.**

So your exported model contains a [`tf.parse_example`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parse_example) op that expects to receive serialized `tf.Example` protos satisfying the feature specification you passed to [`build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/export/build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn), i.e. in your case it expects *serialized examples* that have the `sentence` feature. To predict with the model, you have to provide those serialized protos.

Fortunately, Tensorflow makes it fairly easy to construct these. Here's one possible function to return an expression mapping the `examples` input key to a batch of strings, which you can then pass to the CLI:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def serialize_example_string(strings):

  serialized_examples = []
  for s in strings:
    try:
      value = [bytes(s, "utf-8")]
    except TypeError:  # python 2
      value = [bytes(s)]

    example = tf.train.Example(
                features=tf.train.Features(
                  feature={
                    "sentence": tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=value))
                  }
                )
              )
    serialized_examples.append(example.SerializeToString())

  return "examples=" + repr(serialized_examples).replace("'", "\"")
```

So using some strings pulled from your examples:

```
strings = ["klassifiziere mich bitte",
           "Das Paket „S Line Competition“ umfasst unter anderem optische Details, eine neue Farbe (Turboblau), 19-Zöller und LED-Lampen.",
           "(pro Stimme geht 1 Euro Spende von Pfuscher ans Forum) ah du sack, also so gehts ja net :D:D:D"]

print (serialize_example_string(strings))
```

the CLI command would be:

```
saved_model_cli run --dir /path/to/model --tag_set serve --signature_def predict --input_exprs='examples=[b"\n*\n(\n\x08sentence\x12\x1c\n\x1a\n\x18klassifiziere mich bitte", b"\n\x98\x01\n\x95\x01\n\x08sentence\x12\x88\x01\n\x85\x01\n\x82\x01Das Paket \xe2\x80\x9eS Line Competition\xe2\x80\x9c umfasst unter anderem optische Details, eine neue Farbe (Turboblau), 19-Z\xc3\xb6ller und LED-Lampen.", b"\np\nn\n\x08sentence\x12b\n`\n^(pro Stimme geht 1 Euro Spende von Pfuscher ans Forum) ah du sack, also so gehts ja net :D:D:D"]'
```

which should give you the desired results:

```
Result for output key class_ids:
[[0]
 [1]
 [0]]
Result for output key classes:
[[b'0']
 [b'1']
 [b'0']]
Result for output key logistic:
[[0.05852016]
 [0.88453305]
 [0.04373989]]
Result for output key logits:
[[-2.7780817]
 [ 2.0360758]
 [-3.0847695]]
Result for output key probabilities:
[[0.94147986 0.05852016]
 [0.11546692 0.88453305]
 [0.9562601  0.04373989]]
```

Comment: Works like a charm – fantastic! Thank you very much!

Comment: If you have an answer to my other TF question, I'll be happy to award you another 150 points: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51249989/error-trying-to-convert-tensorflow-saved-model-to-tensorflow-js-model

Comment: Thank you for accepting. I've been taking a look at your other question but so far no progress beyond reproducing the error. I'm involved in a project with a similar requirement... we aren't quite there yet but I will need an answer to it as well. Currently it doesn't look possible without a lot of custom code. I left a comment there to elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, saved_model_cli provides another option `--input_examples`, instead of `--input_exprs`, so that you can pass the tf.Examples data directly in the cmd line, without the manual serialization.

For example:

`--input_examples 'examples=[{"sentence":["this is a sentence"]}]'`

See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#--input_examples for details.

Comment: how can you pass in a batch using this syntax?

Comment: `--input_examples 'examples=[{"sentence":["this is a sentence for example1"]},{"sentence":["this is a sentence for example 2"]}, {"sentence":["this is a sentence for example 3"]}]'`

Comment: `saved_model_cli run --dir . --tag_set serve --signature_def predict --input_examples 'examples=[{"sentence":["this is a sentence"]}]'`
 errors: 
`File .../saved_model_cli.py", line 489, in _create_example_string feature_list)
TypeError: 'this is a sentence' has type str, but expected one of: bytes`

Any idea?

Comment: I noticed this error too, and filed a ticket (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27662), and propose a one-liner fix at the end.

Comment: I left a comment on the issue. I can't believe it's 2019 and nobody has noticed this yet!