# Error Trying to Convert TensorFlow Saved Model to TensorFlow.js Model

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow

I have successfully trained a DNNClassifier to classify texts (posts from an online discussion board). I've created and saved my model using this code:

```
embedded_text_feature_column = hub.text_embedding_column(
    key="sentence",
    module_spec="https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-de-dim128/1")
feature_columns = [embedded_text_feature_column]
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    hidden_units=[500, 100],
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    n_classes=2,
    optimizer=tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.003))
feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns)
serving_input_receiver_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)
estimator.export_savedmodel(export_dir_base="/my/dir/base", serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

Now I want to convert my saved model to use it with the JavaScript version of TensorFlow, *tf.js*, using the [tfjs-converter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter).

When I issue the following command:

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model --output_node_names='dnn/head/predictions/str_classes,dnn/head/predictions/probabilities' --saved_model_tags=serve /my/dir/base /my/export/dir
```

…I get this error message:

> ValueError: Node 'dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_layer/sentence_hub_module_embedding/module_apply_default/embedding_lookup_sparse/embedding_lookup' expects to be colocated with unknown node 'dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_layer/sentence_hub_module_embedding

I assume I'm doing something wrong when saving the model.

**What is the correct way to save an estimator model so that it can be converted with *tfjs-converter*?**

[The source code of my project can be found on GitHub.](https://github.com/pahund/beitragstuev)

Comment: At the moment it doesn't look like this is possible with the available library. Aside from this colocation issue, which seems to come from freezing word embeddings, tfjs-converter [doesn't support all the ops in the graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter/blob/master/docs/supported_ops.md). So even if the main TF library would freeze and restore the graph right, it would still include some unsupported ops like `LookupTableFindV2` and `StringToHashBucketFast`. The README says to file issues to let the devs know which ops to support, but issues aren't currently enabled on the repo.

Comment: Awww, too bad... And surprising, since they have a word embeddings example in the tfjs repo, sentiment analysis of imdb movie ratings, pretty much the same as what I'm doing: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/sentiment

Answer (score 1):

You can try this and I think this will work. Just input your input format in code.

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras \
                       path/to/my_model.h5 \
                       path/to/tfjs_target_dir
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: any luck?  I keep running into Unsupported Ops errors.  Also, is input_format keras correct here?  Thought it was supposed to be tf_saved_model having exported from estimator.export_savedmodel().